# C# Process.kill doesnt have the function only Process.start

Tags: c#

There is only the function to Process start

Example:

```
Process.Start("https://discord.gg/example");
```

And I want to add another option on a bool to close the

```
Process.Kill("https://discord.gg/example");
```

(`Process` does not know the definition for `Kill`) also not for `Process.kill` or `Process.Close`

Is there a other way to Do this?

Answer (score 0):

Check the oficial [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=net-6.0) so you can assign the process to an object, after starting that process within the object, you can "killl it" whenever you want.

Example:

```
    Process myProcess;
    private void startNotepad(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            myProcess = new Process();
            myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "notepad";
            myProcess.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception E)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(E.Message);
        }
    }

    private void killNotepad(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myProcess.Kill();
    }
```